# swift2 filter reminder using start and end dates

Tags: swift2, eventkit, reminders

How to filter reminder using start and end dates `let predicate = eventStore.predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting(today, ending:tomorrow, calendars: [])` am using this method for filter but am getting null value.

Comment: Maybe because you are asking the eventStore to search an empty array of calendars `[]`? Would `calendars:nil` do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for events from an empty set of calendars (you are passing in `[]`). No calendars contain no events ...